# Async task could not keep up with for loop (firebase)

Tags: android, firebase, loops, asynchronous, android-asynctask

```
  for (Uri mUri : mSelected) 
   {
       imagesRef = storageRef.child(postid + mUri.getLastPathSegment());
       imagesRef.putFile(mUri).addOnSuccessListener(task4 ->
       db.collection("posts").document(postid).update("photo_id", FieldValue.arrayUnion(imagesRef.getDownloadUrl())));
   }
```

So, now i am working with firestore and firebase storage. I uploaded (multiple) images to the storage, and when it is uploaded, i get the download url and wants to add it into my firestore. So, the problem is, only the last image is added into firestore, all images are added into storage, but only the last imgUrl is added into firestore. Since firebase uses async tasks i suspect it is because the update task could not keep up with the loop. Any help is very much appreciated !!!

Comment: just to check, does the problem is occur when you upload just 2 images at the same time?

Comment: What's the value of `postid` at every iteration?

Comment: @nada yes, when i post only 1 pic the pic will get uploaded successfully , but when i upload 2 or more, only the last pic get uploaded into firestore

Comment: @AlexMamo postid is created differently everytime, this code is used when i create a new post, thus when a user click "post", i want to upload the pictures to storage and get their url, unfortunately i am only able to upload the last url into firestore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might be with **imagesRef**, it is declared outside of `for (Uri mUri : mSelected) {...}` and therefore it is being replaced before `addOnSuccessListener(...)` responds.

So, declare it locally to `for (Uri mUri : mSelected) {...}` and see if it will not resolve the issue. Like this

```
for (Uri mUri : mSelected) 
{
       var imagesRef = storageRef.child(postid + mUri.getLastPathSegment());
       imagesRef.putFile(mUri).addOnSuccessListener(task4 ->
       db.collection("posts").document(postid).update("photo_id", FieldValue.arrayUnion(imagesRef.getDownloadUrl())));
 }
```

Comment: i tried but it just throws java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException error. do u perhaps know wht this means

Comment: @aishaaishapeng did you change anything else in your code? When you remove the var does it still show the error? And to what line exactly does it point you to?

Comment: thnks man! it works the error was for smtg else. to get the download url i hv to get it on success listener. Youve been great help!